# Quantiles when the population contains only one unique value

Tags: integer-partitions, quantile

My apologies for the mixing of the terms quartile and quantile below. I am interested in the general case of quantiles, but I'm using a quartile as a specific example. Also feel free to clarify any points I seem to be confused or unclear about. Most of my exposure with the subject of quantiles has been using software tools generating partitions, so I'm looking for clarification of these issues from a stricter mathematical formulation.

Suppose we have the following population and that we want to take the quartiles of it:

```
1
1
1
1
```

What would the usual formal definition of a quartile result in? Would each quartile point be 1? Often times, we want to examine the partitions of data divided by the quantile points. What  would we expect to form in this case with formal definitions? 4 partitions containing a single 1?

Comment: You can interpolate, but I'm not sure this is a "standard". E.g. median of $[1, 2, 3, 4] = (2+3)/2 = 2.5$. In your case, yes the quartiles are all 1. The difficult cases seem to be with low sample size and a quantile at one extreme. I think if you had a sample rather than a population and the sample was something like $[1,2,3,4]$ and you were asked for the 10th percentile, say, then you might do some curve fitting and come up with a number < 1. Someone else might be able to answer authoritatively (ask on stats stackoverflow otherwise).

Comment: As statistics to describe spread/(crude) distribution of values, they certainly make little sense if there are few values.

Comment: @vonbrand True. My use case is rather silly: coloring polygons on a map based on some related attributes. I'm trying to convince my client to consider a different coloring scheme, but it had me wondering regardless.

Comment: @TooTone That makes sense. The fact that you don't generally need these kinds of statistics for such a small population would explain why it's so confusing. There would be little need to develop much rigorous work around it. Thanks.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's actually an interesting question because it has an analogy in the real world where you are trying to get quantiles for losses in insurance, for example. Regulations say you need enough capital to survive a 1 in 200 event (i.e. enough to pay your insured clients), so you will try to look at the 0.5th percentile of the distribution where there may be very very few data points. Often this comes down to choosing a  distribution that will have appropriate behaviour in the tails, but choosing the distribution is a lot like saying how you interpolate between points.